Historical Exploration of Cache Coherency Before the MESI Protocol in x86 Architecture
I am interested in exploring how local cache coherency was achieved in the era before automated protocols like MESI were introduced. This topic might vary across different processor architectures, but I’d like to focus specifically on the x86 architecture.
Based on my research, the first x86 processors to support hardware-based cache coherence using the MESI protocol were Intel Pentium processors (P5 architecture). However, it’s possible that earlier solutions relied on simpler or more primitive coherence mechanisms. I’d like to learn more about these earlier approaches.

Context and Specific Questions:

Pre-MESI Cache Coherency:

Before the MESI protocol was implemented in Pentium processors, what mechanisms or protocols (if any) were used to maintain cache coherence in x86 systems? Were there any alternative approaches to address this issue, especially in multiprocessor systems?


Case Study: Intel i486 Processors:

The i486 processors were the first in the x86 line to include an integrated L1 cache. Before this, caches were external (e.g., SDRAM) and located on the motherboard, managed by a chipset’s cache controller.
Given that multiprocessor systems were already present during the i486 era, how was cache coherence achieved for these systems? Did external caches managed by chipsets pose specific challenges?


Approaches in Systems Without Automated Cache Coherency:

In systems where automated cache coherency protocols didn’t exist, was the responsibility of managing synchronization placed on compilers or operating systems? For example, did compilers insert low-level instructions to flush caches or enforce memory synchronization where necessary?
Considering that most major programming languages supported some form of multithreading by the late 80s and early 90s, how were cache-related synchronization issues addressed in such environments?


Java’s Perspective on Early Processors:

Java, introduced in 1995, still supported processors like the Intel i386. Even in single-threaded scenarios, how were issues such as atomicity and cache coherence handled when external caches were shared between processors? Were there specific JVM mechanisms or instructions for addressing this?




The Key Question:
How was cache coherence managed in x86 systems before the introduction of MESI and similar automated protocols? What strategies were employed in multiprocessor systems, and how did compilers, operating systems, or low-level instructions contribute to resolving synchronization challenges?
If any of my assumptions are incorrect, I’d be glad to have them clarified. Thank you for your insights!

This might get better answers at Retrocomputing.SE.

https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28376/did-486-smp-systems-provide-total-store-ordering seems quite relevant.

How was cache coherence managed in x86 systems before the introduction of MESI and similar automated protocols? - Cache coherency has always been hardware-supported in systems that had caches at all.  (Including cache-coherent DMA).  386 mobos with cache might have had memory-side cache.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I486#Differences_between_i386_and_i486 says 486 had "an enhanced external bus protocol to enable cache coherency".  There were 486 SMP systems; Intel's memory model docs talk about stuff that applies in 486 and newer.  (386 SMP existed but I seem to recall reading that it was mostly a 3rd-party hack or something?  And the memory model was stronger, fully sequentially consistent if my previous research was correct: Did 486 SMP systems provide Total Store Ordering? )

Even in single-threaded scenarios, how were issues such as atomicity and cache coherence handled when external caches were shared between processors - Why would they need to be "handled" in any particular way by user-space JVMs?  Kernels make sure that migrating a process to another core is fully transparent no matter what it was in the middle of, usually by acquire/release synchronization between cores.  (And maybe a serializing operation, in case it was doing self-modifying code.)
